# How to combine old style figures and mathematical expressions?

Tags: classicthesis, oldstylenums, arsclassica

I'm using the ArsClassica package to write my thesis in chemistry. This package uses old style figures for text and inline figures for math. My problem is, that I have to use a couple of figures with corresponding units (therefore in math mode) in text. So sometimes I get OSF and inline figures in the same paragraph or even in the same sentence, as you can see in the first picture. Does this look good to you? I am not really convinced. The other possibility is to globally disable OSF, but I think this destroys the beauty of the style, especially in the toc. Or to use only OSF (second picture). The authors of ClassicThesis und ArsClassica themselves hardly used any figures with units in their documentations.
From a typographical point of view, what would you recommend? Or is there even another option?

I found a similar discussion concerning ClassicThesis with its author, André Miede (https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/issues/53/make-switching-off-of-the-old-style). He suggested to use the Euler math mode. But for me this is impossible, because there are no italic letters and I think not a single supervisor at my university accepts upright symbols like p for pressure und V for volume (instead of *p* and *V*).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SE! My personal two cents is that the second, where the numerals match and are all in old style, looks substantially better than the first.

Comment: @chsk Thanks for your opinion! Is the second one for you only better or really satisfying? Imagine K instead of Degree Celsius - the different heights of figure and letter are enormous.

Comment: @Sargos I can't say whether it's *truly* satisfying, certainly not based on a comparatively small snippet -- keep in mind I'm no typographer either --; but the first strikes me as visually bumpy, as it were. When reading a text like that, I'd be stumbling over the different styles of numerals, and that'd be distracting, which is why I think the second is preferable. But YMMV, and at the end of the day, beauty is always in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: These `300\,{\footnotesize °C} or 636\,{\small °C} and 636\,\textmu m` look decent to me, see how you like them.